# `new': allocator undefined for Data (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, oop, rubygems

I began creating my ruby program procedurally. I am now re-factoring so it could be object oriented. Right now I am trying to simply instantiate the object and call a method.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @var1 = var1
    @var2 = var2
  end

  def open_excel_file
    @var1 = Spreadsheet.open 'file.xls'
    @var2 = var1.worksheet 'Sheet'
  end
end

object = MyClass.new
object.open_excel_file
```

When I run the program I receive the following:

`new': allocator undefined for Data (TypeError)

What I'm mainly trying to do is basically store what's inside of the excel sheet on to an object. The file only has two columns with numbers inside of them. I was able to do this the procedural way but not the object oriented way.

Comment: What do you expect `var1` and `var2` to be inside `initialize`?

Comment: Since I'm very new to this I don't know.